# Adding Values to Complex Django View

Tags: python, django, view, django-models

I am trying to get a dictionary of values from the `Photographer` model to appear in my form. Afterwards, the user will select a `Photographer`, submit the form (along with other information), and an instance of the model `A` will be created with the `Photographer` as an attribute. Although I understand ModelForms can be a lot more friendly, I must use BaseForm in this case:

```
@login_required
def create_in(request, slug):
    element = get_object_or_404(Element, slug=slug)
    a = A.objects.create(element=element, user=request.user)
    a.save()
    return redirect('CreationEditView', pk=a.pk)
```

The `urlconf` sends the user to `create_in,` where the user selects the  `element` then is redirected to `CreationEditView,` which uses the [BaseUpdateView](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py) from Django Generic Views to manipulate the object:

```
class EditView(BaseUpdateView):
    model = A
    form_class = AForm
    context_object_name = 'a'
    page = 'edit.html'

    def get_element(self):
        return self.object.element

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        element = self.get_element()
        return render_page(self.request, element,
                           self.page, context)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('view_all')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EditView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(EditView, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(active=True, user=self.request.user)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super(EditView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super(EditView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(EditView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

class CreationEditView(EditView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(EditView, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(active=False, user=self.request.user)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('create_finished',
                       kwargs=dict(pk=self.object.pk))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreationEditView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['create'] = True
        return context
```

The page is then rendered via `render_page`, which looks like:

```
def render_page(request, element, page, context):
    template_name = element_template_name(element, page)
    try:
        template = get_template(template_name)
    except TemplateDoesNotExist:
        template = get_template('template_location/%s' % page)
    context = RequestContext(request, context)
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

If my models are like:

```
class Photographer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    models = models.ManyToManyField('Model')

class Model(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    series = models.ForeignKey('Series', null=True, blank=True)

class A(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    photographer = models.ForeignKey('Photographer', blank=True, null=True)
    model = models.ForeignKey('Model', blank=True, null=True)
```

How would you go about getting the values from `Photographer` to be properly integrated into the view code to use later in the template? These values will be part of a drop down form that a user will select from. A usage example would be very helpful.

Thanks for any ideas.

EDIT (added the form)

---

```
class AForm(BaseForm):
    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, instance=None, auto_id='id_%s',
                 prefix=None, initial=None, error_class=ErrorList,
                 label_suffix=':', empty_permitted=False):

        if not instance:
            raise NotImplementedError("Instance must be provided")

        self.instance = instance
        object_data = self.instance.fields_dict()
        self.declared_fields = SortedDict()
        self.base_fields = fields_for_a(self.instance)

        # if initial was provided, it should override the values from instance
        if initial is not None:
            object_data.update(initial)

        BaseForm.__init__(self, data, files, auto_id, prefix, object_data,
                          error_class, label_suffix, empty_permitted)

        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

        # save fieldvalues for self.instance
        fields = field_list(self.instance)

        for field in fields:
            if field.enable_wysiwyg:
                value = unicode(strip(cleaned_data[field.name]))
            else:
                value = unicode(cleaned_data[field.name])

        return self.instance
```

Comment: What's your actual problem? I really don't get your point. If AForm is a ModelForm for the model A, it should provide you directly with the field for the foreign key, that will be that dropdown that you want.

And by the way, if you don't need to change anything, don't override the method in your class.

Comment: Why are you doing this: `class EditView(BaseUpdateView):` instead of this: `class EditView(UpdateView):`? Is there a reason i'm not seeing? Anyway, like @pyriku said, i don't understand your problem. Try to edit your question to express your problem better...
`

Comment: Thank you for your responses. The question is really just how to access the fields from the database. In php I would query the database directly then use those values in my form. Not sure how to get the values from the `ManyToManyField` 'Model' using Django and given the structure above... Supplemental info: AForm is not a Model Form, it is using `BaseForm`, which may have caused a deal of the confusion. Sorry for that. I added the form above. Comments and suggestions are appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @pyriku: I have edited the question to fully elaborate the problem. Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: BaseForm? Why doesn't simply use ModelForm? I'm sorry but I don't get that over-complication you're dealing with.

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem is. Can you add a comment to your code to show where you want `Photographer` to be integrated, or provide some pseudo code of what you want to do? If you have access to an instance of `Photographer`, why can't you do `instance.models.all()` to access the M2M relation?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @TonyAbou-Assaleh. The problem is getting the values from the `Photographer` database model into the template given the structure above, using `BaseForm` as the form structure. `Photographer` has many values, I just want to know a way to get these values so I can use them in the template. It would be easier using `ModelForm`, but I have to operate within the structure provided above. I have tried a lot of different methods, but been unsuccessful.

Comment: I would prefer using `ModelForm` @pyriku, also, because it is much more thoroughly documented, but I need to know how to integrate this using `BaseForm`. That is why I am offering a bounty for this difficult question. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to add a form field to AForm that will show a list of photographers associated with the given instance of the `A` model. Correct? So basically you need to replicate the forms.ModelChoiceField functionality in `AFrom`. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @TonyAbou-Assaleh: Yes that is exactly my issue. Sorry if it was unclear before. Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 5):

I think you are missing a fundamental aspect of Django programming, the Django form.  You should create a form like:

```
class AForm(forms.Form):
    model = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Model.objects.all())
    photographer = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Photographer.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('model', 'photographer', )
```

Then your create view would look something like:

```
@login_required
def create_in(request, slug):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/somewhere/")
    else:
        form = AForm()
    return render_to_response('create_in.html', { 'form': form }, context_instance=context)
```

It's hard to figure out what you are trying to do,  I think you are getting overly tricky as I've never needed to extend BaseForm and I've done lots of forms with special filters on the selection.  Usually these are done something like:

```
class AForm(forms.Form): 
   def __init__(self, profile, *args, **kwargs):
       super(AForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['photographer'].queryset = models.Photographer.objects.filter(profilephotographer__profile=profile)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. What if I am generating the form using Django's (BaseForm Class)[https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py]?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Added the form using `BaseForm` above. I would like to use `forms.Form` for the form, but the scenario is more complex than that and I'm already dealing with a structure as above. Thank you for your elaboration of how to construct using generic forms. Any ideas on how to integrate given `BaseForm` would be appreciated, as well. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks again for your response @Rob Osborne. I appreciate your continued support. Trying to use `self.fields[''].queryset` with BaseForm has resulted in an attribute error: `object has no attribute 'fields'`, as I guess BaseForm does not support the fields attribute. I understand that using BaseForm is a little archaic, but I must use BaseForm for this project. Any other ideas of how to include an additional queryset into my form as structured are appreciated.

Comment: In a BaseForm subclass, the fields will not exist until after the call to __init__.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Rob Osborne. I am very appreciative of your opinion. Any idea why calling         `self.fields['photographers'].queryset = Photographer.objects.all()` after `BaseForm.__init__` results in a **KeyError**? Or a hint as to how to solve this error? Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Is the key error because fields doesn’t have 'photographers' or because fields['photographers'] doesn't have a queryset?

Comment: Thanks again @Rob Osborne. The traceback says: `KeyError at 'photographers'`. Any ideas on how to solve this KeyError? I've been struggling with this one for a while. I appreciate your advice.

Comment: Based on what you have above, this line should actually be `self.fields['photographer'].queryset = Photographer.objects.all()`.  Note the singular photographer.

Comment: Thanks again @Rob Osborne. Switching to `photographer` did not fix the KeyError, unfortunately. Any clues as to why I might be getting a KeyError when I try to include this query? I really appreciate your advice, thank you