# Over-Ride __init__: Extending Forms (Python/Django)

Tags: python, django, forms, extend

Struggling to figure out how to Over-Ride the `__init__()` method in my Django Form to include additional values from the database. I have a group of photographers that I am trying to list as a form option for the user. Afterwards, the user's photographer selection will be added (along with other information) to the database as an instantiation of a new model.

This is a continuation, or elaboration, of my other [Current Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548992/adding-values-to-complex-django-view). @Rob Osborne has given me some great advice helping me understand how to extend `BaseForm`, but I still cannot get my code to execute. The linked question lists my models, form, and views, if you are interested. While I understand that using ModelForm is easier and more documented, I must use BaseForm in this instance.

Here is what I have:

```
class AForm(BaseForm):
    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, instance=None, auto_id='id_%s',
                 prefix=None, initial=None, error_class=ErrorList,
                 label_suffix=':', empty_permitted=False):

        self.instance = instance
        object_data = self.instance.fields_dict()
        self.declared_fields = SortedDict()
        self.base_fields = fields_for_a(self.instance)

        BaseForm.__init__(self, data, files, auto_id, prefix, object_data,
                      error_class, label_suffix, empty_permitted)
        self.fields['photographer'].queryset = Photographer.objects.all()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        if not commit:
            raise NotImplementedError("AForm.save must commit it's changes.")

        if self.errors:
            raise ValueError(_(u"The Form could not be updated because the data didn't validate."))

        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

        # save fieldvalues for self.instance
        fields = field_list(self.instance)

        for field in fields:
            if field.enable_wysiwyg:
                value = unicode(strip(cleaned_data[field.name]))
            else:
                value = unicode(cleaned_data[field.name])
```

Using the above code results in a `KeyError at 'photographer'`.

I appreciate any ideas / comments on how to resolve this KeyError so that I can get the `photographer` values into my form. Thank you!

---

EDIT:

Trying to use super, as recommended by @supervacuo, but still getting a `KeyError at photographer` as before:

```
class AForm(BaseForm):
    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, instance=None, auto_id='id_%s',
             prefix=None, initial=None, error_class=ErrorList,
             label_suffix=':', empty_permitted=False):

        super(AForm, self).__init__(data, files, auto_id, prefix, object_data,                         error_class, label_suffix, empty_permitted)
        self.fields['photographer'].queryset = Photographer.objects.all()
```

What could I be missing that is generating the KeyError? Thanks for any advice.

---

EDIT 2: adding `fields_dict()`

from models.py

```
class A(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def fields_dict(self):
        fields_dict = {}
        fields_dict['title'] = self.title

        for key, value in self.fields():
            fields_dict[key.name] = value.value

        return fields_dict
```

Thanks for any advice.

---

EDIT 3: (edited `class AForm` above in the initial question as well, to include more information)

```
def fields_for_a(instance):
    fields_dict = SortedDict() 
    fields = field_list(instance)

    for field in fields:
        if field.field_type == Field.BOOLEAN_FIELD:
            fields_dict[field.name] = forms.BooleanField(label=field.label, required=False, help_text=field.help_text)
        elif field.field_type == Field.CHAR_FIELD:
            widget = forms.TextInput
            fields_dict[field.name] = forms.CharField(label=field.label, required=field.required, max_length=field.max_length, help_text=field.help_text, widget=widget)

            fields_dict[field.name] = field_type(label=field.label,
                                             required=field.required,
                                             help_text=field.help_text,
                                             max_length=field.max_length,
                                             widget=widget)

    return fields_dict
```

---

EDIT 4: def fields(self). from models.py:

```
    def fields(self):
        fields_list = []
        fields = list(self.category.field_set.all())
        fields += list(Field.objects.filter(category=None))

        for field in fields:
            try:
                fields_list.append((field, field.fieldvalue_set.get(ad=self),))
            except FieldValue.DoesNotExist:
                pass  # If no value is associated with that field, skip it.

        return fields_list

    def field(self, name):
        if name == 'title':
            return self.title
        else:
            return FieldValue.objects.get(field__name=name, ad=self).value
```

Comment: Are you using a ModelForm or a normal Form? It's not clear in the original question. If you are using a normal Form, you need to add the fields to the form.

Comment: I'm using BaseForm, not ModelForm. Thanks for the comment. [This is a link](http://docs.nullpobug.com/django/trunk/django.forms.forms.BaseForm-class.html) to BaseForm info. [This is a link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py) to django's source BaseForm class. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Um, I didn't down vote anything. I wasn't sure which you were using

Comment: Apologies, must have been someone else

Comment: I realise you've said that you need to do things this way in your other question, but why? This whole thing could be done in about 3 lines with a `ModelForm`. What requires you to extend `BaseForm` instead?

Comment: There is also a indentation error in your code; can you paste the exact snippet?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the indentation error @supervacuo. I am building on top of a project, which requires me to use BaseForm to avoid rebuilding the structure.

Comment: How are you utilizing this class? Where are you creating an object of it?

Comment: Thanks @Burhan Khalid. If you look at my other question ([Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548992/adding-values-to-complex-django-view)), it is used in the UpdateView.

Comment: This is still incomplete. `models.Model` does not define a `fields()` method; you must have added it yourself. Where is it?

Comment: There is a line, somewhere in your codebase, that looks like `def fields(self):`. Please post that line, and the body of the `fields()` function itself.

Comment: Thanks again @supervacuo, I believe I have added the relevant code snippets to the edit above. I will be more than willing to provide more information if necessary. Thanks for your input and patience with this issue

Comment: -1 I give up. This is the first we're hearing about the `Category`, `Field` and `FieldValue` models, and — again! — you haven't provided any of the code for them. In short, I am almost certain your `fields_dict` method isn't returning the correct result. I don't know (because you haven't told us) why you're using such a convoluted arrangement, and there's no way of knowing what the problem is with so much missing from your posted code.

Comment: Thanks for helping me @supervacuo. I tried my best to include the __relevant__ code, but lacking an understanding of the error was preventing me from knowing what to post. I apologize for any frustration this may have caused you. I have decided to take another route and start from scratch on a fully new project. However, I still would like to figure out how to solve my problem in order to improve my understanding of python. The full code is available at [GitHub Here](https://github.com/saebyn/django-classifieds) if you have any interest in continuing to help out a lost soul.

Comment: I appreciate any ideas, and have started a small bounty to help express my gratitude. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Will be offering a bounty, but currently experiencing the bug described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141671/why-cant-i-start-a-bounty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That GitHub link should've been the **first thing in your question**.

The [`django-classifieds` application](https://github.com/saebyn/django-classifieds) has an entire system of dynamic fields (based on the `Field` and `FieldValue` models) which is why you're having trouble. If you don't fully understand this aspect of `django-classifieds`, I recommend you base your project on something else instead.

Looking down the list of `FIELD_CHOICES` in `django-classified`'s `models.py`, you can't use this database-driven field system to define relationsips — so there's no dynamic per-category `ForeignKey` field!

The alternative would be to add a `photographer` field on your `A` model (any particular reason you've renamed it from `Ad`?), as it seems you have done based on your other question. To go the rest of the distance, however, you'd need to edit the `fields_dict()` method like so:

```
def fields_dict(self):
    fields_dict = {}
    fields_dict['title'] = self.title
    fields_dict['photographer'] = self.photographer

    for key, value in self.fields():
        fields_dict[key.name] = value.value

    return fields_dict
```

Comment: Thank you very much @supervacuo. A very thorough explanation. In my effort to boil down and simplify my question, I have made it much more difficult to understand. I apologize for the confusion, and very much appreciate you taking a moment to elaborate. This didactic process has granted me a lot of knowledge, and I thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `BaseForm.__init__` seems wrong; you should be using [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super), like so

```
class AForm(BaseForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(AForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['photographer'].queryset = Photographer.objects.all()
```

(as actually recommended in Rob Osbourne's accepted answer to your other question).

Beyond that, I am suspicious of your `fields_dict()` method, which isn't part of Django and you haven't provided the definition for. Confirm with `print self.fields.keys()` that, for whatever mysterious reason, `photographer` is not there, then post the code for `fields_dict()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @supervacuo. I have tried implementing `super()` as illustrated in the edit to my question above. Unfortunately, I still cannot figure out why there is a `KeyError at photographer`. Any ideas that can help me solve this issue? Thanks very much

Comment: Please read the second part of my answer. Add the code for `fields_dict()` to your question.

Comment: Added `fields_dict()` to my question above. Thanks for any advice @supervacuo.

Comment: See above. Please add definition for `self.fields()` as well. And any other custom model methods called by `self.fields()`, in case that saves some time...

Comment: Thanks for looking at my problem @supervacuo. I added more information to `class AForm` in the initial question, along with all information I could find relating to `self.fields()`. I appreciate any advice!